# Alternative to 'className' in JavaScript for IE Mobile?

Tags: javascript, ie-mobile

I'm working on a mobile web app that needs to work in IE Mobile. I've narrowed down a JavaScript error I'm getting to IE Mobile not supporting the '`className`' property (IE4 engine...). I'm trying to find an alternative that works across all browsers with minimal code changes (I already have a few libraries that use '`className`').

The easiest approach I could think of would be to modify IE's element prototype to include className (if it doesn't have it), the problem is that I don't know what the alternative to '`className`' is in IE Mobile.

I've tried this:

```
element.className = element.class;
```

Which obviously doesn't work because `class` is a keyword in JavaScript and my JS compressor doesn't like it, and it's probably not valid anyway.

Other than using 'setAttribute()' everywhere I need to modify an element's class, is there any property I can use that is the equivalent to className?

Comment: "...IE4 engine" - ouch! and I thought supporting IE6 was hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't avoid using `setAttribute()`, you can take a line out of the jQuery playbook and use a helper procedure with an optional parameter. This code is untested, but ought to work:

```
var className = function (obj, value)
{
    if (value !== undefined)
    {
        return obj.setAttribute ('class', value);
    }
    return obj.getAttribute ('class');
};

// Use as
alert (className (element));
className (element, "foo");
alert (className (element));
```

Answer (score 1):

No attribute, no.  I'm afraid you're stuck with getAttribute() and setAttribute().

Answer (score 1):

Following up on what John Millikin, you could even make that function part of IE's element prototype:

```
Element.prototype.getClass = function() {
    return obj.getAttribute ('class');
}
Element.prototype.setClass = function(newClass) {
    return obj.setAttribute('class', newClass);
}
```

or if you want a combo method like John provided ...

```
Element.prototype.className = function(newClass) {
    if (!newClass)
        return this.getClass();
    return this.setClass(newClass);
}
```

Comment: P.S.  Given that elements can have multiple classes, you may even (I dunno how complex your app is) want to make these functions advanced enough to add/remove specific classes, without making the user do a ton of string parsing to preserve the existing classes.  I'll leave the details of that to you